# Necessary and sufficient conditions for non-empty intersection of a finite number of balls in $R^k$

Tags: general-topology

Let $x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}$ be points in $R^k$. Let $B(a,r)$ denote an open ball with centre at $a$ and radius $r$. Prove that $x_{j} \in B(x,r)\hspace{3pt} \forall \hspace{3pt} j $ if and only if $x \in \bigcap_{j=1}^{n}B(x_{j},r)$.

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you for pointing it out. I will make the necessary edits.

Comment: Balls do not have origins.  They have centers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a picture for the case $n=2$ will show what is happening pretty clearly

The "$\impliedby$" direction: To say $x \in \cap_{j=1}^{n} B(x_j , r)$ means exactly that $x \in B(x_j , r)$ for all $j$.  That means the distance between $x$ and $x_j$ is less than $r$ for all $j$.  Namely $x_j \in B(x,r)$ for all $j$

The "$\implies$" direction: To say $x_j \in B(x , r)$ for all $j$ means the distance between $x_j$ and $x$ is less than $r$ for all $j$.  Namely $x \in B(x_j,r)$ for all $j$, so $x \in \cap_{j=1}^{n} B(x_j , r)$